# Connect ESP32 Arduino to Azure Event Grid Using MQTT

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventgrid, arduino-esp32

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

// Wi-Fi settings
const char* ssid = "T-HUB2.0";
const char* password = "Innovation";

// Azure Event Grid settings
const char* mqttBroker = "eventgrid1.southeastasia-1.ts.eventgrid.azure.net";
const int mqttPort = 8883;
const char* eventGridTopic = "Topics/topic1";
const char* username = "client1-authnID";
const char* deviceID = "client1-sessionID1";

// TLS/SSL client setup
WiFiClientSecure wifiClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(wifiClient);

// Certificates
const char* caCert = "";

const char* clientCert = R"KEY(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)KEY";

const char* clientKey = R"KEY(
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIAb/hcl7cXX8gHH8gjlhXjcaj8pTonHP+MzqcS2rHY13oAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEmvEdmUuMBNnORlOjAKVjP7vRe/0KNQ0YUulT7K9s2tDk17jvQoTh
N7acbvBt/67MjOGz4/SOgwGTHmx1221/0w==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
)KEY";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(2000);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  // Load CA certificate, client certificate, and client key
  wifiClient.setCACert(caCert);
  wifiClient.setCertificate(clientCert);
  wifiClient.setPrivateKey(clientKey);

  // Set MQTT server and port
  mqttClient.setServer(mqttBroker, mqttPort);

  // Set MQTT callback function
  mqttClient.setCallback(callback);

  // Connect to MQTT broker
  connectToMqttBroker();
}

void loop() {
  if (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    // Reconnect to MQTT broker if the connection is lost
    connectToMqttBroker();
  }
  mqttClient.loop();

  // Publish message to Event Grid
  publishEvent();

  // Delay before publishing the next event
  delay(5000);
}

void connectToMqttBroker() {
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT broker...");

    if (mqttClient.connect(username, deviceID,"")) {
      Serial.println("Connected to MQTT broker");
    } else {
      Serial.print("Failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(" Retrying in 5 seconds...");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  // Handle incoming MQTT messages here if needed
}

void publishEvent() {
  // Create the event message
  DynamicJsonDocument eventMessage(256);
  eventMessage["id"] = "1";
  eventMessage["subject"] = "Example Event";
  eventMessage["eventType"] = "example.event";
  JsonObject eventData = eventMessage.createNestedObject("data");
  eventData["key"] = "value";

  // Serialize the event message to a JSON string
  String jsonMessage;
  serializeJson(eventMessage, jsonMessage);

  // Publish the event message to Event Grid
  mqttClient.publish(eventGridTopic, jsonMessage.c_str());
}
```

I am trying to connect esp32 to Azure Event grid using MQTT. However, it keeps disconnecting with this message.

```
Failed, rc=-2 Retrying in 5 seconds...
Connecting to MQTT broker...
```

I was previously able to connect to the same client using MQTTX.
[image]

I presume the issue is with the username or client-id. It is successfully connecting to the wi-fi but it is nit connecting to the mqtt broker. How can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: Did you follow up this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-certificate-chain-client-authentication?

Comment: yes i had read it to generate certificates. It is connecting through mqttx so certificates are not an issue. Just some problem with the code syntax/username/client-id

Comment: You mean the MQTTX Client is working well (connecting and publishing on topic, etc.), right?

Comment: Yes MQTTX is working perfectly fine. I am able to publish and subscribe to topics.

Comment: So, it looks like the username or client-id is not a problem. IMHO, the issue is in your implementation, using the mqtt library. Sorry, I am using C# for ESP32 (M5Stack AtomLite) without any problem with connecting to Azure Event Grid MQTT Broker, publishing, etc., basically the mqttclient/connect are using  all values like in the MQTTX Client.

Comment: @RomanKiss Thanks a lot. How are you programming the ESP32 without using Arduino IDE. And if possible, could you share the code ?

Comment: have a look at https://www.nanoframework.net/, I am using a Visual Studio 2022 and C# for coding. (extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nanoframework.nanoframework-vs2022-extension)   Here is a M2Mqtt library (v3.1, v3.1.1 and v5.0) https://github.com/nanoframework/nanoFramework.m2mqtt/tree/main what is used in my pilot projects., see also https://github.com/nanoframework,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nanoframework

Comment: Did you manage to get your code work? Have a similar story with mqttx working perfectly, but cannot get it with a library.

Comment: @Oleksandr Nope, i gave up trying to connect to azure iot hub/event grid using arduino and mqtt. It is working perfectly with aws using the same code. No matter what changes i made in the code or the certificates, it always gave rc = -2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after multiple attempts I managed to make it work.

My goal was to intergrate with ESP Home, but steps should be reusable for bare ardiono as well.
I documented the whole ESP Home solution here on GitHub Gist: [ESPHome: Connecting to Secure MQTT Server from esp 8266 / esp32](https://gist.github.com/alex-tomin/fafb36269719ef944bb093f7fa2d3a99#file-mqttgrid-h).