# Unable to connect esp32 MQTT to azure IOT Hub

Tags: azure, arduino, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, arduino-esp32

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

// Wi-Fi settings
const char* ssid = "T-HUB2.0";
const char* password = "Innovation";

// Azure IoT Hub settings
const char* mqttServer = "PASSDEMO1.azure-devices.net";
const int mqttPort = 8883;
const char* deviceId = "iotdevice01";
const char* connectionString = "SharedAccessSignature sr=PASSDEMO1.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fiotdevice01&sig=XXXXX&se=1687851087";

// TLS/SSL client setup
WiFiClientSecure wifiClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(wifiClient);

// MQTT topics
const char* telemetryTopic = "devices/iotdevice01/messages/events/";

// MQTT callback function
void mqttCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  // Handle incoming MQTT messages here if needed
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  // Set MQTT server and port
  mqttClient.setServer(mqttServer, mqttPort);

  // Set MQTT callback function
  mqttClient.setCallback(mqttCallback);

  // Connect to MQTT broker
  connectToMqttBroker();
}

void loop() {
  if (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    // Reconnect to MQTT broker if the connection is lost
    connectToMqttBroker();
  }
  mqttClient.loop();

  // Send telemetry data to Azure IoT Hub
  float temperature = readTemperature();
  char telemetryMessage[100];
  snprintf(telemetryMessage, sizeof(telemetryMessage), "{\"temperature\": %.2f}", temperature);
  mqttClient.publish(telemetryTopic, telemetryMessage);

  delay(5000);
}

void connectToMqttBroker() {
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT broker...");

    if (mqttClient.connect(deviceId, connectionString, "")) {
      Serial.println("Connected to MQTT broker");
      //mqttClient.subscribe("devices/your-device-id/messages/devicebound/#");
    } else {
      Serial.print("Failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(" Retrying in 5 seconds...");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

float readTemperature() {
  // Code to read temperature from sensor
  // Replace this with your own code
  return 25.0;
}
```

I tried connecting to azure iot Hub using the above code. It is giving me this error.

```
Failed, rc=-2 Retrying in 5 seconds...
Connecting to MQTT broker...
```

Not just IOT Hub but IOT Central and Event Grid is also giving the same error when i try to publish/subscribe using MQTT. It is not able to connect in the first place. Can someone debug the issue ? Does esp32 not connect to azure services using pubsubclient or should i modify the mqtt broker in some way ?

Comment: Same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76523502/connect-esp32-arduino-to-azure-event-grid-using-mqtt).

Comment: @Sampath I didnt get any solution

Comment: I do recommend to read this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/iot-mqtt-connect-to-iot-hub

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to connect to Azure IoT Hub using `PubSubClient` instance.

This is the line where you are trying to establish a connection with IoT Hub. `if (mqttClient.connect(deviceId, connectionString, ""))`. I have looked into the implementation of PubSubClient file and there is no implementation of `connect` method defined in the file that accepts a connection string as parameter. You can find this method on your machine probably under the following directory "C:\Users<username>\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PubSubClient\src\PubSubClient.cpp". I believe this is causing the connection to fail.

If you are using Arduino IDE to test this connection, use can use [azure-sdk-for-c-arduino](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c-arduino/tree/main) source code. The link [How to Setup and Run Azure SDK for Embedded C IoT Hub Client on Espressif ESP32](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c-arduino/tree/main/examples/Azure_IoT_Hub_ESP32) provides the configuration and set up steps needed to establish the connection. This code sample uses [az_iot_hub_client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c-arduino/blob/main/src/az_iot_hub_client.c) which is used to establish the connection with IoT Hub.

If you prefer not to use Arduino IDE, please refer the steps provided in [Connect an ESPRESSIF ESP32 using Azure IoT Middleware for FreeRTOS](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-middleware-freertos-samples/tree/main/demos/projects/ESPRESSIF/aziotkit) to establish the connection.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: It dosent even connect to the host. Even if i change the hostname to something random, it gives the same output.

Comment: I haven't tested the code with ESP32 but I have tested it with ESP8266 and it worked as expected. I could connect to IoT Hub. I have just provided the settings in the iot_configs.h file as suggested in the github. What output do you see when you test the code. May I know the value you are trying to set for the IOT_CONFIG_IOTHUB_FQDN

Comment: Can you try running the exact code above on esp32 and connecting using the pubsubclient ? I am able to connect using the github library but i want it to connect specifically using MQTT Which is why i am using the code above. It is disconnecting with error code 2. What is IOT_CONFIG_IOTHUB_FQDN and where do we find it ?

Comment: I do not have ESP32 handy with me. Please note that the code sample still uses MQTT as a protocol to communicate with IoT Hub. It is just using a different client for establishing connection. Refer to [Set and Run instructions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c-arduino/tree/main/examples/Azure_IoT_Hub_ESP32#setup-and-run-instructions) of the github code for instructions on how to use the SDK. You would need to set the values for the parameters in iot_configs.h file. You can get the FQDN by referring to Hostname of your IoT Hub on Azure portal. It will be <HubName>.azure-devices.net